# Keep a dictionary of methods with unknown signature to be invoked with reflection

Tags: c#

I want to have a dictionary which uses strings as keys and something that represents methods, ***all of which may have different signatures***, as values. From this something, I should be able to access a `MethodInfo` and an instance of an object if the method is not static, such that later on I can find it by name and invoke it using reflection.

I thought `Delegate` would do, but I cannot find a way to cast a static or instance method into a `Delegate`. I could also create my own class or structure that holds an object and a `MethodInfo`, but if so, my class' users would have to get a `MethodInfo` off of whatever method he wants to add to my dictionary and would need to add a reference to `Reflection` everywhere (instead of perhaps just passing the method itself or something like `(Delegate)myMethod`). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered using a DI Container? Because this is essentially what they do. You wire the dependencies together at the composition root, and then you can have them injected at runtime. Internally it uses a dictionary very similar to this (except it is wired by type and not by string).

Comment: @TravisJ is there such thing in the .NET Framework or would I need to import a library?

Comment: You would need to import a library and do a lot of configuration. If you are not aware of the topic it is definitely non trivial to learn about and implement. However, if you are looking at doing what your question states, I believe a DI Container (Dependency Injection Container), also called an Inversion of Control container, would be best practice. Common ones are structure map, ninject, unity, autofac. If you are serious about it, you should probably look into getting a book on the subject. This one is good: [Dependency Injection in .NET](http://www.manning.com/seemann/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind specifying a delegate type each time you add to the dictionary, then you can use `Delegate`:

```
void A() {}
string B(string arg) { return arg; }

void Test()
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, Delegate>();

    dict.Add("A", new Action(A));
    dict.Add("B", new Func<string, string>(B));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you just want to have a `Dictionary<string, Action>` which you can wire up with lambda functions:

```
var actions = new Dictionary<string, Action>();

actions.Add("Foo", () => Console.WriteLine("Bar!"));

Car myCar = new Car();
actions.Add("Vroom", () => myCar.Drive());

actions["Foo"](); //prints "Bar!"
actions["Vroom"](); //invokes myCar.Drive
```

This way all the different signatures, or object references, or static methods, or whatever are handled by the lambda and its closure semantics.

If you want to be able to pass some context or inputs to the set, you can provide an untyped `context` object which you can cast when you register the method. Instead of having a parameterless `Action` you would have an `Action<object>` instead:

```
var actions = new Dictionary<string, Action<object>>();

var JuanLuisSoldi = new Person();
actions.Add("Lunch Time", context => JuanLuisSoldi.Eat((Food)context));

Food lunch = new Apple();
actions["Lunch Time"](lunch);
```

Comment: Will I be able to invoke these methods without knowing the parameters count and type until run-time (such as by getting a `MethodInfo` off of them which I don't know how to)?

Comment: Once you find out how many parameters the method takes and what types the parameters are, how do you plan on retrieving/instantiating those objects to pass in as arguments? I think you need to be more clear on what it is you are doing or attempting to achieve.

Comment: They'll be taken from a expression string written in a custom language (is quite a simple lambda-like language for which I already wrote a parser and I'm happy with it so no need to suggest any third party library, please). So parameter mapping needs to be done fully at run-time.

Comment: Would [McGarnagle's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17664652/1269654) using `DynamicInvoke` work for you? As in `object[] args = GetObjectArgumentsFromMyCustomLanguage(); dict["A"].DynamicInvoke(args)`?

Comment: Yeah it will I was really just waiting to see if another solution would come up before accepting the answer. Plus my code is already very close to his solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways, this is one way:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public IDictionary<string, Action> ActionRegistry { get; set; }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        // Registering an action that doesn't use reflection:
        ActionRegistry.Add("SomeAction", () => { Console.WriteLine("Hello");});

        // Registering an action that uses reflection
        object objectInstance; = ...
        Type type; = ...
        string methodName; = ...
        object[] arguments; = 
        ActionRegistry.Add("SomeAction2", () =>
        {
            type.GetMethod(methodName).Invoke(objectInstance, arguments);
        });

        // Invoking:
        ActionRegistry["SomeAction2"]();
    }
}
```

You can regard the lambda/Action as a adapters. I use similar dictionaries a lot when I reflect.

Comment: Will I be able to invoke these methods without knowing the parameters count and type until run-time (such as by getting a `MethodInfo` off of them which I don't know how to)?

Comment: Yes. (But you need to write to write the code that finds out how to invoke the method at run-time of course). I've updated the answer.