# Type safe way to return values from a scripting language in C#

Tags: c#

I have been working on a small mathematical scripting engine (or DSL, if you prefer). Making it for fun, its nothing serious. In any case, one of the features I want is the ability to get results from it in a type safe manner. The problem is that there are 5 different types that it can return.

Number, bool, Fun, FunN and NamedValue. There is also AnyFun which is a abstract base class for Fun and FunN. The difference between Fun and FunN is that Fun only takes one argument, while FunN takes more then one argument. Figured it was common enough with one argument to warrant a separate type (could be wrong).

At the moment, I am using a wrapper type called Result and a class called Matcher to accomplish this (inspired by pattern matching in languages like F# and Haskell). It basically looks like this when you use it.

```
engine.Eval(src).Match()
  .Case((Number result) => Console.WriteLine("I am a number"))
  .Case((bool result) => Console.WriteLine("I am a bool"))
  .Case((Fun result) => Console.WriteLine("I am a function with one argument"))
  .Case((AnyFun result) => Console.WriteLine("I am any function thats not Fun"))
  .Do();
```

This is my current implementation. It is rigid, though. Adding new types is rather tedious.

```
public class Result
{
    public object Val { get; private set; }
    private Callback<Matcher> _finishMatch { get; private set; }

    public Result(Number val)
    {
        Val = val;
        _finishMatch = (m) => m.OnNum(val);
    }

    public Result(bool val)
    {
        Val = val;
        _finishMatch = (m) => m.OnBool(val);
    }

    ... more constructors for the other result types ...

    public Matcher Match()
    {
        return new Matcher(this);
    }

    // Used to match a result
    public class Matcher
    {
        internal Callback<Number> OnNum { get; private set; }
        internal Callback<bool> OnBool { get; private set; }
        internal Callback<NamedValue> OnNamed { get; private set; }
        internal Callback<AnyFun> OnAnyFun { get; private set; }
        internal Callback<Fun> OnFun { get; private set; }
        internal Callback<FunN> OnFunN { get; private set; }
        internal Callback<object> OnElse { get; private set; }
        private Result _result;

        public Matcher(Result r)
        {
            OnElse = (ignored) =>
            {
                throw new Exception("Must add a new exception for this... but there was no case for this :P");
            };
            OnNum = (val) => OnElse(val);
            OnBool = (val) => OnElse(val);
            OnNamed = (val) => OnElse(val);
            OnAnyFun = (val) => OnElse(val);
            OnFun = (val) => OnAnyFun(val);
            OnFunN = (val) => OnAnyFun(val);
            _result = r;
        }

        public Matcher Case(Callback<Number> fn)
        {
            OnNum = fn;
            return this;
        }

        public Matcher Case(Callback<bool> fn)
        {
            OnBool = fn;
            return this;
        }

        ... Case methods for the rest of the return types ...

        public void Do()
        {
            _result._finishMatch(this);
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is that I want to add more types. I want to make so functions can return both numbers and bools, and change Fun to Fun< T >, where T is the return type. This is actually where the main problem lies. I have AnyFun, Fun, FunN, and after introducing this change I would have to deal with AnyFun, Fun< Number >, Fun< bool >, FunN< Number >, FunN< bool >. And even then I would want it to match AnyFun against any function that isnt matched themselves. Like this:

```
engine.Eval(src).Match()
  .Case((Fun<Number> result) => Console.WriteLine("I am special!!!"))
  .Case((AnyFun result) => Console.WriteLine("I am a generic function"))
  .Do();
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for a better implementation, that handles adding new types better? Or are there any other suggestions for how to get the result in a type safe manner? Also, should I have a common base class for all the return types (and add a new type for bool)?

Performance is not an issue, btw.

Take care,
Kerr

EDIT:

After reading the feedback, I have created this matcher class instead.

```
public class Matcher
{
    private Action _onCase;
    private Result _result;

    public Matcher(Result r)
    {
        _onCase = null;
        _result = r;
    }

    public Matcher Case<T>(Callback<T> fn)
    {
        if (_result.Val is T && _onCase == null)
        {
            _onCase = () => fn((T)_result.Val);
        }
        return this;
    }

    public void Else(Callback<object> fn)
    {
        if (_onCase != null)
            _onCase();
        else
            fn(_result.Val);
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        if (_onCase == null)
            throw new Exception("Must add a new exception for this... but there was no case for this :P");
        _onCase();
    }
}
```

Its shorter, but the order of the cases matter. For example, in this case the Fun option will never run.

```
.Case((AnyFun result) => Console.WriteLine("AAANNNNNNNYYYYYYYYYYYYY!!!!"))
.Case((Fun result) => Console.WriteLine("I am alone"))
```

But it will if you switch places.

```
.Case((Fun result) => Console.WriteLine("I am alone"))
.Case((AnyFun result) => Console.WriteLine("AAANNNNNNNYYYYYYYYYYYYY!!!!"))
```

Is it possible to improve that? Are there any other issues with my code?

EDIT 2:

Solved it :D.

Comment: This is a really neat idea, I wonder if you could inherit from a base class to use the curiously reoccurring template pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).
See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8189558/1445661

Note this will only work for your own created reference types since they'll need to derive from your base return type.

Is this sort of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Ok, will check them out. Number is a struct at the moment, but I may have to change that since I am going to turn it into a custom Complex type with better accuracy (Complex has some rounding issues I want to avoid). One possibility is to have a base interface instead of a base class, but I am not sure if its a good solution or not, lol.

Comment: `AnyFun` matches before `Fun`, because an instance of `Fun` `is` `AnyFun` in `_result.Val is T` - `is` checks for type compatibility. Sounds like (but I'm not sure - haven't read this thoroughly) you want an exact type check: `_result.Val.GetType() == typeof(T)`.

Comment: Actually I dont want an exact type check, since I want to be able to have AnyFun as default if you dont care what kind of function it is. Not sure how to implement a "most specific wins", though.

Comment: Well, one way would be to store a `_default` if it's compatible but not an exact match - in the same way that you currently store `_onCase` - only set a `_default` if it isn't already set. That way, the first non-specific match wins on `_default` in the same way as the first *specific* match wins on `_onCase`. In `Do()`, if `_onCase` is null, call `_default`, and if both are null, throw the exception.

Comment: I think I solved it. I store the type of the last match, and then compare it when a new case is given using IsAssignableFrom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your matcher could handle unlimited types by doing something like this:

```
public class Matcher
{
    private readonly Result result; // pass this in
    private readonly List<Func<Result, bool>> cases = new ...();

    public Matcher Case<T>(Action<T> action)
    {
        cases.add(result =>
        {
            if(typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(result.Value.GetType()))
            {
                action((T)(result.Value));
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        return this;
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        for each(var @case in cases)
        {
            if(@case(result)) return;
        }
    }
}
```

I think you don't actually need a list, unless your `Result` doesn't have a `Value` until later on. I don't quite understand your object model, but if the type of the result is known, then don't use a list and just do the type test immediately.

Comment: You inspired a solution. One without a list at that (Value is known). Dont know if its any good, though.

Answer (score 0):

### If you always want to treat a DSL result in the same way

If you always want to treat a result in the same way (such as if you always want to convert/adapt a specific type of DSL object in the same manner), I suggest using one or more dictionaries where you put adapter delegates [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17664623/1105687).

I don't know exactly how you plan to extend your application, but it seems to me like it's a good idea in your case to have one separate dictionary per return type, and let them all have zero or one input parameters. (Instead of using several parameters, just wrap the DSL parameters that you want to return into one single object).

An example:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public IDictionary<Type, Action<object>> RegistryVoid { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<Type, Func<object, int>> RegistryInt { get; set; }

    public void SomeDlsMethod()
    {
        ...

        // Example when you need to convert your DSL data object to int:
        int value = RegistryInt[someDslObject.GetType()](someDslObject);
    }
}
```

### If you want to treat a DSL result differently

If you want to treat a DSL result differently in your code, I suggest using the TypeSwith [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/299120/1105687). TypeSwitch is simply a simpler way than using multiple if/else-statements and casting. With this approach you can specify the logic where you use it, so you are not limited to the logic you put into the dictionaries. (TypeSwitch can easily be modified to become an extension method if you prefer that).

Example:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public void SomeDlsMethod()
    {
        TypeSwitch.Do(someDslObject,
            TypeSwitch.Case<DslObjectA>(someDslObjectA => ...),
            TypeSwitch.Case<DslObjectB>(someDslObjectB => ...),
            TypeSwitch.Default(() => ...)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will check out the links :).