# Wrappers for unrelated types to enable generic constraints in C#

Tags: c#, generics

If you have a generic type that needs to contain a bool or a custom number type called `Number`, would it be a bad idea to create a wrapper type for bool and make so both the wrapper and `Number` inherits from the same base class? So that you instead of `MyClass<bool>` would have `MyClass<BoolWrapper>`?

It would be to ensure you could only do `MyClass<RightType>`, where the `RightType` is the `bool` wrapper, the `Number` type or the common base class. `MyClass<WrongType>` would not be allowed. It basically stands between this and splitting `MyClass` into two classes, a `MyClassWithBool` and a `MyClassWithNumber`. The reason for this is due to a DSL I am making. I might want to have a method that does something like this to avoid boilerplate code:

```
public void Bind<T>(MyClass<T> m) { ... }
```

But that would allow giving the wrong types, so I want to be able to do something like this:

```
public void Bind<T>(MyClass<T> m) where T : BaseClass { ... }
```

Then I wouldnt need:

```
public void Bind(MyClassWithBool m) { ... }
public void Bind(MyClassWithNumber m) { ... }
```

Take care,
Kerr.

Comment: What makes the bool / number type unique from other types? Are they literals in your DSL ?

Comment: Lol, no, its basically a mathematical DSL that can return a number, a bool (for comparisment) or a function. The function can return either a number or a bool. I also have a pattern matching type mechanism that allows getting the result in a more type safe manner (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17683886/type-safe-way-to-return-values-from-a-scripting-language-in-c-sharp). Want to make so you cant "pattern match" against cases that doesnt make sense, like a function that returns a list, since the lanuage only have numbers, bools and functions. MyClass is actually the function class.